# USB3 needed for RPi based NAS?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, nas, raspberry-pi

I am wanting to build a RPi NAS, following more or less the following instructions: https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/build-a-raspberry-pi-nas

I have the two USB drives (2 TB each), but I only own a RPi 3 - no USB3 ports. However, I would have to attach my home-grown NAS to the WiFi modem, in order to have it usable anywhere in my house.

This limits of course the bandwidth with which I'd be able to access the NAS. So the question is - should I invest in a RPi 4 for this project? Wouldn't the extra bandwidth gained by USB 3 lost on the WiFi communication? I would attache the NAS via cable to the router though.

I know I can make some theoretical calculations based on the WiFi specs, but I am interested in ***real experience and real expectations on performance***.

The router is a tp link wr840n with nominal 300 Mbps. I am aware that I would never get the same performance from such a RPi based setup than from a dedicated commercial NAS or anything like that. I am just curious about if a RPi 4 is required.

Thanks

Comment: I think there may be an answerable question in here somewhere, if you re-cast it to not be a product or opinion-based request. Please also don't use the comments space for additional information, edit your question.

Comment: for the record iirc the LAN port of a rpi3 is capped at 300Mbps and it shares the 480Mbps theoretical bandwidth of its USB 2.0 bus. Whether you "need" a rpi4 instead really depends on how fast (or "future-proof") you need your "NAS" to be.

Comment: There are lots of RPi 4 benchmarks out there that you can find on Google. It seems like the USB 3 performance to an SSD tops out at ~350MB/s read and ~220 MB/s write. That's more than enough for running two hard drives at full 7200 RPM performance. Your bottleneck will probably still be the gigabit LAN anyways, which has a theoretical max speed lower than USB 3.0 anyway.

Comment: Great comments, and made me realize one thing. I will hold off buying a RPi4 first and simply try the whole setup I have available. I will then be able to "feel" how well it works for me. I then can upgrade it to RPi4 if I decide it's not doing as well as I would like to.